# Cannot find module in VueJS Error using a JSON file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router

I was given a task in finding a way to dynamically import pages inside vuejs projects; built with a CLI tool the team I am in, is working on. I tried using functions as a string ("() => import(...)") and then eval that string and that did not work. Currenly I have used:

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "name": "Login",
            "path": "/login",
            "component": "../../src/pages/auth/login/*"
        },
        {
            "name": "Register",
            "path": "/register",
            "component": "@/pages/auth/register"
        }
    ]
}
```

then I use a "driver" to then pass into our routes.ts file:

```
import * as dynamicRoutes from './routes.json';

const routes: any[] = [];
dynamicRoutes.default.routes.forEach((elem: any) => {
    const component = async () => await require(elem.component).then((comp: any) => comp);
    routes.push({
        name: elem.name,
        path: elem.path,
        component,
    });
});

export default routes;
```

Which im getting "cannnot find module" errors. Also when i log the output i get this when i check the component function: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.invokeGetter.

Is there a way that i can dynamically pass routes using this json file? (Because we are reading and writing to/from the json file to keep/update the routes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic imports to lazy load Vue components, and it's even [included by default when you install vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk)

`const component = () => import(elem.component)`

Comment: That was my first option as mentioned is used both string and actual component import and got the same error

Comment: You don't need to write the import as a string, just the path (as is written in my code section)

Comment: You can't import with `@` if you're loading the path from the string because webpack replaces `@` with a relative path on compilation, but your path doesn't get compiled. You'll have to use a relative path (or replace `@` with a relative path in the code)

Comment: i have both paths there to test and neither of them works

Answer (score 0):

when you say dynamically import pages, I believe it is something related to lazy load the component dynamically ? If so, you need to have a HOC for all your route components which can basically use es6 import() (promise based) to fetch the component . You can also use webpack magic comments for the same(if you are using webpack). 
hope it helps

Comment: No need for a HOC, this is a built-in functionality of vue-router